# cq5.4 - restore system administrator group

Tags: aem

in cause of a failed user Import the System Administrator Group was deleted.
The admin User is still there and can act as admin, but some Features (like activating Pages) are disabled as button (right click on page -> activate works).

Is there a way to restore the System Administrator Group? Can i Export it from another instance and Import it on the damaged instance?

Thanks
Patrick[image]

Comment: ok found that the package cq-content holds this Information. Is it safe to reinstall this package? Should i reinstall all Hotfixes which are installed right now after reinstall the Content package?

Answer (score 0):

Open Package Manager from CRX Menu and reinstall the cq-content package. All Default users will be created again with the right ACL.